# Express as sum of powers

Tags: algorithms

How to find if a number can be expressed as sum of two perfect powers. That is, given $x$, I have to find if there exists non negative integers $a, b, m, n$ such that $a^m + b^n = x$.

Comment: I suppose you also want $m, n > 1$.

Comment: You may want to check http://oeis.org/A070049

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start by enumerating the perfect powers $\le x$.